# How to Peek Ahead at a Character Without Passing that Character?

Tags: c++

I am doing an implementation of an expression evaluator where the user can type in a binary number with the 0b prefix. I want to be able to (using a string iterator), peek ahead to see if the next character in the expression after the 0 is a b, and if it is, to not pass by that b character and to go back a character to the 0 at the start of the prefix (something like ungetc). Is there a way to unget a character that has been passed over in a string?

What I've tried:

```
Token::pointer_type Tokenizer::_get_number( Tokenizer::string_type::const_iterator& currentChar, Tokenizer::string_type const& expression ) 
{

assert( isdigit( *currentChar ) && "currentChar must pointer to a digit" );
Integer::value_type const MAX_UNSIGNED_D10 = (std::numeric_limits<Integer::value_type>::max()-10)/10;
Integer::value_type accumulator = *currentChar++ - '0'; 

//Binary Numbers
if( *currentChar == '0' )
{
    if( *currentChar++ == 'b'  )
    {
        BinaryInteger::value_type binAccum = _get_binary( currentChar, expression );
        return make<BinaryInteger>( binAccum );
    }
}
}



Token::pointer_type Tokenizer::_get_number( Tokenizer::string_type::const_iterator& currentChar, Tokenizer::string_type const& expression ) 
{

assert( isdigit( *currentChar ) && "currentChar must pointer to a digit" );
Integer::value_type const MAX_UNSIGNED_D10 = (std::numeric_limits<Integer::value_type>::max()-10)/10;
Integer::value_type accumulator = *currentChar++ - '0';

std::stringstream iss( expression );


//Binary Numbers
if( iss.get() == '0' )
{
    if( iss.get() == 'b'  )
    {
        BinaryInteger::value_type binAccum = _get_binary( currentChar, expression );
        return make<BinaryInteger>( binAccum );
    }
}
}
```

Also have tried using [] access for the string expression's characters itself but that is extremely limiting to certain cases.

Comment: Please show your actual code. What have you tried so far? Do you know that you can use the `+` and `-` operators on an iterator without actually moving the iterator's current position? Do you know that you can make copies of an iterator?

Comment: Done, please check over what I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call the `++` operator on an iterator, it advances the iterator to the next element.  To peek at the next element without advancing the iterator, you can use `+1` instead, eg:

```
if( *currentChar == '0' )
{
    if( *(currentChar+1) == 'b'  )
    {
        BinaryInteger::value_type binAccum = _get_binary( currentChar+2, expression );
        return make<BinaryInteger>( binAccum );
    }
}
```

Just be careful if `currentChar` is already at the end of the string before you peek.  The next element after the current one will be the string's `end` position, and you should not dereference that iterator value.  You might want to consider adding an extra parameter to your tokenizer so it can detect when it reaches the end of the input string and does not iterate too far.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `stringstream` [peek](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/) is what you need (it's inherited from `istream`, just like `unget`. Stringstraems are streams working with `string`. They work the same as file streams and the default I/O streams like `cin` and `cout`.

Comment: Could you possibly give me a small example of how to do do this based off the code I edited in above? I am trying to do something with peek but I do not think I am doing it right.

Comment: Your code is really complicated. I don't know why you made it so hard for yourself, but in your case, `if(expression[0]=='0'&&expression[1]=='b')` should be sufficient...

Comment: Well it's not my code that is what is making this so difficult. It's a code base from my professor. I already have that above line working in the main tokenizer method and it works. The issue I'm having is with binary numbers in the middle of an expression where [0] and [1] won't work, at that point it wont be able to recognize the binary.

Comment: you can get the length of the `string` by calling `size()`. Then you can view the contents in a loop: `for(unsigned int i=2;i<expression.size();i++) if(expression[i]!='0'&&expression[i]!='1') ITSNOTABINARY;`.